# подсветить рамку поля при ошибке в валидации

Tags: javascript, input

подскажите как подсветить рамку поля в красный цвет на 5 секунд, если в поле была допущена ошибка

```html
<span>Фамилия получателя</span>
<input type="text" size="90px" id="surname"><br>
<input type="button" value="Сохранить" onclick="go()">
<script>
  function go() {
    var snl = document.getElementById('surname').value.length;
    if (snl == 0) {
      alert("все поля должны быть заполнены");
      document.getElementById('surname').focus();
      return;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function go() {
  var el = document.getElementById('surname');
  var snl = el.value.length;
  if (snl == 0) {
    alert("все поля должны быть заполнены");
    el.classList.add("warning");
    el.focus();
    setTimeout(function() { 
      el.classList.remove("warning"); 
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

```css
.warning {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Фамилия получателя</span>
<input type="text" size="90px" id="surname"><br>
<input type="button" value="Сохранить" onclick="go()">
```

Comment: что означает стрелочка  "=>" перед  el.classList.remove("warning")  ?

Comment: @РоманРомашко https://learn.javascript.ru/es-function#funktsii-cherez

Comment: и еще хотел узнать, когда вы присвоили переменной   var snl значение   el.value.length; то вы присвоили значение и длину одновременно, я так полагаю?

Comment: @РоманРомашко Вообще-то, это Ваша строчка ). В этой строчке длина строки `....value.length` записывается в переменную `snl`.

Comment: извиняюсь тогда, просто уже много раз переписываю значение, по этому может где то ошибся